# I'm having trouble animating a Blur (UWP Composition Api)

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I cannot get this animation to work, am I missing something? I'm basically just trying to animate an Image to animate into a blurred image after one second:

Here is the **XAML**:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Image x:Name="TestImage"
           Source="Assets/test.jpg"
           Stretch="Uniform"
           Margin="100">
    </Image>
</Grid>
```

Here is the associated **CODE-BEHIND**:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    TestImage.Loaded += (sender, e) =>
    {
        var element = sender as UIElement;
        var visual = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(element);
        var compositor = visual.Compositor;

        var effect = new GaussianBlurEffect()
        {
            Name = "Blur",
            Source = new CompositionEffectSourceParameter("Backdrop"),
            BlurAmount = 0f,
            BorderMode = EffectBorderMode.Hard,
        };

        var blurEffectFactory = compositor.CreateEffectFactory(effect, new[] { "Blur.BlurAmount" });
        var brush = blurEffectFactory.CreateBrush();
        var destinationBrush = compositor.CreateBackdropBrush();

        brush.SetSourceParameter("Backdrop", destinationBrush);

        var sprite = compositor.CreateSpriteVisual();
        sprite.Brush = brush;

        var anim = compositor.CreateScalarKeyFrameAnimation();
        anim.InsertKeyFrame(0.0f, 0f);
        anim.InsertKeyFrame(1.0f, 50f);
        anim.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

        ElementCompositionPreview.SetElementChildVisual(element, sprite);

        sprite.Brush.StartAnimation("Blur.BlurAmount", anim);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
sprite.Brush.StartAnimation("Blur.BlurAmount", anim);
```

To

```
sprite.Brush.Properties.StartAnimation("Blur.BlurAmount", anim);
```

**UPDATE:**
Ok. I found the issue. You're not setting a size to your backdrop `SpriteVisual`.
Add to you code:

```
sprite.Size = new Vector2(1000, 1000);
```

By default it's zero.

Comment: Still not working  :(   But  thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: @Maximus I updated the answer try to set some size to sprite.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `Size` for the `SpriteVisual`, so that you cannot see the blur, you need to set a `Size` for it, for example:

```
var sprite = compositor.CreateSpriteVisual();
sprite.Brush = brush;
sprite.Size = new Vector2(500, 500);
```